# How to do a shift operation in R data.table, while appending an additional row for one last comparison?

Tags: r, data.table

Here are some data:

```r
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

foo <- data.table(
  date = seq.Date(from = as_date('2020-01-01'), to = as_date('2020-03-01'), by = '1 month'),
  a = rep(1:3, 2),
  group = c(rep('a', 3), rep('b', 3))
)
```

```r
> foo
          date a group
1: 2020-01-01 1     a
2: 2020-02-01 2     a
3: 2020-03-01 3     a
4: 2020-01-01 1     b
5: 2020-02-01 2     b
6: 2020-03-01 3     b
```

The desired output is the following:

```r
         date a group diff
1: 2020-01-01 1     a    1
2: 2020-02-01 2     a    1
3: 2020-03-01 3     a    1
4: 2020-04-01 0     a   -3
5: 2020-01-01 1     b    1
6: 2020-02-01 2     b    1
7: 2020-03-01 3     b    1
8: 2020-04-01 0     b   -3
```

And here follows my own solution.

```r
bar <- foo[foo[, .I[which.max(date)], by = group]$V1]
bar <- bar[a != 0][, c('date', 'a') := .(date %m+% months(1), 0)]
foo <- rbindlist(list(foo, bar))
foo[, diff := a - shift(a, fill = 0), by = group]
foo[order(group, date)]
```

I wonder if a more compact solution exists in `data.table`, such as a `fill` option able to look at the past with a `shift` operation performed from the point of view of future non-existent data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more compact but it's largely similar:

```
foo[
  order(date),
  .(date = c(date, date[.N] %m+% months(1)), a = c(a, 0)),
  by = group
][ , diff := a - shift(a, fill=0)][]
```

I guess we could also do things in one query:

```
foo[
  order(date),
  .(
    date = c(date, date[.N] %m+% months(1)),
    a = c(a, 0),
    diff = c(a - shift(a, fill=0), -a[.N])
  ),
  by = group
]
```

another option that may be more palatable:

```
foo[
  order(date),
  {
    out <- rbind(
      .SD,
      data.table(
        date = date[.N] %m+% months(1),
        a = 0
      )
    )
    out[ , diff := a - shift(a, fill=0)]
    out
  },
  by = group
]
```

Comment: Nice options, thanks. A good point indeed is the use of `.N` after an `order` to get the group's last point, instead of my painful `.I` step.

Comment: @fzenoni in the scope of a larger analysis, you might also want to setkey(foo, group, date) so that no order() is necessary